# Stuck with Gerrit installation

Tags: http, gerrit

I started using Gerrit Code Review, and am stuck with the installation. I have the gerrit.conf file inside the "etc" folder in gerrit.

I am getting the following error:
[image]

Here's my gerrit.config file:

```
        [gerrit]
           basePath = git
           canonicalWebUrl = http://localhost:8081/
        [database]
           type = mysql
           hostname = localhost
           database = reviewdb
           username = gerrit2
        [index]
           type = LUCENE
        [auth]
           type = HTTP
        [receive]
            enableSignedPush = false
        [sendemail]
            smtpServer = localhost
        [container]
            user = mvemur001c
            javaHome = C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_65\\jre
        [sshd]
             listenAddress = *:29418
        [httpd]
             listenUrl = http://*:8081/
        [cache]
             directory = cache
```

Do I need to to do anything else? Should I write the something like the below code ? If else where should I write this apache config file?

```
  <VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName localhost

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
  <Location "/login/">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
 AuthBasicProvider file
 AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
 Require valid-user
</Location>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't let Gerrit and Apache run on port 8081 simultaneously. Apache fails to start, right? Please refer to the [docs](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.2/config-reverseproxy.html). You are currently connecting directly to Gerrit instead of through Apache.

Change the port numbers specified at `<VirtualHost *:8081>` and `canonicalWebUrl`.